# How to get resize helper on the left bottom corner in LimberGridView?

Tags: javascript, gridview, frontend

I'm trying to render LimberGridView. I managed to customize the drag and drop. I have the resize helper on the right bottom corner but I can't figure out how to get the resize helper on the left bottom corner. I have read the wiki page but I can't find anything on it. I am initializing it like so.

```
const limberGridView = new LimberGridView({
    el: el.current,
    itemMouseDownMoveCheck: itemMouseDownMoveCheckFn,
    callbacks: {
        renderContent: renderContentFn,
        renderComplete: renderCompleteFn,
        resizeComplete: resizeCompleteFn,
        moveComplete: moveCompleteFn,
        addComplete: addCompleteFn,
        removeComplete: removeCompleteFn,
        renderPlugin: renderPluginFn,
        removePlugin: removePluginFn,
    },
    positionData: positionData,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `showBottomLeftResizeGuide: true` under publicConstants.

You can have either resize helper on the left bottom corner or the default move helper. But not both. The default move helper can be customized so you won't be needing it. You can have resize helper on the left bottom corner and a customized move helper.

```
const limberGridView = new LimberGridView({
    el: el.current,
    itemMouseDownMoveCheck: itemMouseDownMoveCheckFn,
    callbacks: {
        renderContent: renderContentFn,
        renderComplete: renderCompleteFn,
        resizeComplete: resizeCompleteFn,
        moveComplete: moveCompleteFn,
        addComplete: addCompleteFn,
        removeComplete: removeCompleteFn,
        renderPlugin: renderPluginFn,
        removePlugin: removePluginFn,
    },
    publicConstants: {
        showBottomLeftResizeGuide: true
    },
    positionData: positionData,
});
```